# Can not using contain cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, contain

I want to select data of questions from quizdetails table. And data of questions will be join with answers table, too. So I using code php:

```
$questions = $this
    ->QuizDetails->find()
    ->contain([
        'Questions' => function($q) {
            return $q->contain(['Answers']);
        }
    ])
    ->where(['QuizDetails.quiz_id' => $id]);
```

file AnswersTable:

```
$this->table('answers');
$this->belongsTo('Questions', [
    'className' => 'Publishing.Questions',
    'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
]);
```

file QuizDetailsTable:

```
$this->table('quiz_details');
$this->belongsTo('Questions', [
    'className' => 'Publishing.Questions',
    'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
]);
```

So, when i run it, through a error
**Questions is not associated with Answers**

If I using:

```
$question = $this->Questions->find()->contain(['Answers'])
```

That is ok.
Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you just need to contain Questions and Answers within QuizDetails , if so simply try:

```
$questions = $this->QuizDetails->find()->contain(['Questions.Answers'])
             ->where(['QuizDetails.quiz_id' => $id]);
```

Comment: I have try it, and still error: Questions is not associated with Answers

Comment: if so does this really containing answers, $question = $this->Questions->find()->contain(['Answers']) ?

Comment: do answers belong to questions ??

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have seen my wrong. Change to 'className' => 'Publishing.Questions' -> 'className' => 'Questions'

Answer (score 0):

Because of two tables are not assosiated. You should define the condition to connect.

```
$this->belongsTo('Questions', [
        'className' => 'Publishing.Questions',
        'conditions' => ['A.id' => 'B.id'], //add this
]);
```

P/s: I'm ad form FB Cakephp Viet who answer your posted question in there.

Answer (score 0):

problem from: 'className' => 'Publishing.Questions'
And I change file QuizDetailsTable to:

```
$this->table('quiz_details');
$this->belongsTo('Questions', [
        'className' => 'Publishing.Questions',
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
]);
```

That is OK

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

you have to define both ways.

this ...

```
$this->table('answers');
$this->belongsTo('Questions', [
    'className' => 'Publishing.Questions',
    'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
]);
```

... and this:

```
$this->table('question');
$this->hasMany('Answers', [
    'className' => 'Publishing.Answers',
    'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
]);
```

In your example you only can do this:

```
$answer = $this->Answers->find()->contain(['Questions']);
```